# Is there a way to check the result of the assertions at run time in PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, loops, phpunit, conditional-statements

The following assertion will produce a `.` or an `F` when PHPUnit is run:

```
$this->assertEquals('foo', $bar);
```

But what if I wanted to know the result of the assertion within the test itself? Something similar to:

```
if ($this->assertEquals('foo', $bar)) {
    // log or do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

There's probably no good reason to conditionally run assertions (or maybe there is), but this is a question purely from the debugging point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit uses exceptions to signify that a test has failed.

If we follow the `assertEquals()` code through, we can see that [on line 137 of isEqual.php](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.6/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php#L137), a new `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException` is thrown if the operands are not equal. The test runner then converts this to a "F" for the console output and also uses if for reports etc.

You can catch the Exception and do what you like with it in your testcase. You may want to rethrow it if you still want the test to fail:

```
try {
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $bar);
    // do something else
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
    // log or do something
    throw $e; // rethrow to make sure that the test still fails
}
```